# Populate and Paginate an sub document on Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

My Post Object contains an array of Comments Object, I need to Populate Comments based on offset and limit (Paginated).

It works with mongoose API but I need it with `mongoose-paginate-v2`.

```
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id)
        .populate("author")
        .populate("manufacturer")
        .populate({
            path: "comments",
            populate: "author",
            options: {
                sort: { created_at: -1 },
                skip: (pageNumber - 1) * limit,
                limit: limit,
            },
     })
```

It has to be with `mongoose-paginate-v2` framework because I need some extra properties like total.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.paginate(filter, options).then(async function(result)
where in the option there will be 
populate: {
        path : 'item1',
        populate : {
          path : 'item2'
        }
      },
```

Comment: note that you can't use item1.item2, it has to be nested for each item. I fell to this trap myself and had to question.